# How to setup web.config to see the complete error message for ASP.NET MVC3 project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

How to setup web.config to see the complete error message for  ASP .NET MVC3 project remotly?

So I need a detailed error info...

I have this under web.config but it seems doesn't work...

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="off" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Yup we need `<customErrors mode="off" />` and also we have to restart website under IIS.